# Fetching Image from particular div Only via DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have website, where i have posted few images inside particular div :-

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="separator">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
        <p>Be, where I am today, and i will be one where you will search me tomorrow</p>
    </div>
    <div class="separator">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/imagesda.jpg" />
        <p>Be, where I am today, and i will be one where you will search me tomorrow</p>
    </div>
.... few more images
</div>
```

And from my 2nd website, i want to fetch all images on that particular div.. I have below code.

```
<?php
$htmlget = new DOMDocument();

@$htmlget->loadHtmlFile('http://www.example.com');

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $htmlget);
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//img/@src" );

foreach ($nodelist as $images){
    $value = $images->nodeValue;

    echo "<img src='".$value."' /><br />";
}
?>
```

But this is fetching all images from my website and not just particular div. It also prints out my `RSS` image, `Social icon` image, etc.,

Can i specify particular div in my php code, so that it only fetch image from `div.posts` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first give a "id" for the outer div container. Then get it by its id. Then get its child image nodes.

an example:

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsById('node_id');

$table = $tables->item(1);

//get the number of rows in the 2nd table
echo $table->childNodes->length; 

//content of each child
foreach($table->childNodes as $child)
{
echo $child->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
}
```

may be this like will help you. It has a good tutorial.
    http://www.binarytides.com/php-tutorial-parsing-html-with-domdocument/

Comment: Yes, the link is helpful... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With PHP Simple HTML Parser, this will be:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html=file_get_html("http://your_web_site.com");
foreach($html->find('div.posts img') as $img_posts){
    echo $img_posts->src.<br>; // to show the source attribute
}
```

Still reading about PHP Simple HTML Dom parser. And so far, it's faster(in implementation) than regex.

Comment: is it faster than DOMXPath ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another code that may help. You are looking for

```
doc->getElementsByTagName
```

which can help target a tag directly.

```
<?php
$myhtml = <<<EOF
<html>
<body>
<div class="posts">
    <div class="separator">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
        <p>Be, where I am today, and i will be one where you will search me tomorrow</p>
    </div>
    <div class="separator">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/imagesda.jpg" />
        <p>Be, where I am today, and i will be one where you will search me tomorrow</p>
    </div>
.... few more images
</div>
</body>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($myhtml);

$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    foreach ($div->attributes as $attr) {
      $name = $attr->nodeName;
      $value = $attr->nodeValue;
     echo "Attribute '$name' :: '$value'<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Demo here http://codepad.org/keZkC377

Also the answer here can provide further insights
[Not finding elements using getElementsByTagName() using DomDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073708/not-finding-elements-using-getelementsbytagname-using-domdocument)

Comment: My point is to fetch image from specified div and not just all image from my page. Fetching all image from my page works with my code too. but it also fetches unwanted image from my page. so, i want to restrict my code to fetch image from particular div and not as a whole page.